# Reactivecocoa binding UIButton's title

Tags: ios, uibutton, reactive-cocoa

```
RAC(self.balanceLabel,text) = RACObserve(self.viewModel, balance); // balanceLabel is a UILabel,that is ofcourse work
RAC(self.supplierNameButton.titleLabel.text)  = RACObserve(self.viewModel, supplierName); // that is not work,i think this is I don't use the - setTitle:forState: method
```

My question is:how can i use Reactivecocoa binding the view model's supplier to the UIButon text of its UIControlStateNormal

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, bindings only work for properties and button's text can only be updated using `setTitle:forState` method.

But there is a workaround: you can use `rac_liftSelector:withSignalsFromArray` method, which is helpful when you don't want to mess with subscriptions (and `weakify` / `strongify`):

`[self.supplierNameButtonButton rac_liftSelector:@selector(setTitle:forState:) withSignalsFromArray:@[RACObserve(self.viewModel, supplierName), [RACSignal return:@(UIControlStateNormal)]]];`

Answer (score 0):

The title needs to be updated in a subscription block

```
@weakify(self)
[RACObserve(self.viewModel, supplierName)
    subscribeNext:^(NSString *supplierName) {
        @strongify(self)
        [self.supplierNameButton setTitle:supplierName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
```

By moving the subscription to a category method on UIButton

```
 - (void)setTitleSignal:(RACSignal *)titleSignal forState:(UIControlState)state {
    @weakify(self)
    [titleSignal subscribeNext:^(NSString *title) {
        @strongify(self)
        [self setTitle:title forState:state];
    }];
```

}

the binding can be expressed a bit cleaner as

```
[self.supplierNameButton setTitleSignal:RACObserve(self.viewMode, supplierName) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```